# how to customize DataEntryActivity for card.io

Tags: card.io

is there a way to set the screenOrientation of io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity to be landscape? I tried to set it in Manifest but app crashed with error

```
             io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity requires attribute android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

so, how could I customize this page? if I can't,  is there a way that just delete this page? I think only credit card number should be enough for me and I don't need the expiration  date.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Jeff with the PayPal card.io team. The current DataEntryActivity does not support landscape, but we definitely should not be crashing. We've opened a bug for that issue.

Regarding the request to remove the activity altogether, we require this activity for users without cameras or otherwise unable to scan their card, and to review the card number captured.  You can remove expiry through the intent extra like so:

```
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, false);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, Jeff. I tried to set it false,  and the expiry is gone, which is good. but the page is still there and I have to click the 'done' button to go back to my app. is there a way that maybe let it auto go back to my app instead of click the 'done' button. Actually, I just want find a way so that users won't see this page. Since I can't customize its layout to fit my app's theme.

Comment: I'm Mike with card.io. Jeff is correct - we do require that confirmation view be displayed to your users. Note that users in our other apps (PayPal, LivingSocial, Uber, etc.) all see the same confirmation view, so hopefully it's not too much of a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

Since last SDK version, v3.1.3, you don't need show the confirmation screen. Just put this intent extra:

```
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, true);
```